# Brakes are soft

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, silverado

I had spongy brakes and they replaced the master cylinder.  Now I have a soft brake pedal,  meaning they worked but the pedal goes down farther than it ever has.  What could be causing this, air in the line?  another leak?  didn't see a leak.  This is on a 06 chevy silverado crew cab 1500 2wd

Comment: What kind of shop or technician did the work?  Do you know (or can you ask) if they used the proper scan or diagnostic tool to do a brake bleed including the Antilock Braking System (ABS) circuits?

Comment: NTB did the work.

Comment: Honestly, you should just drive back and demand them to finish the job.

Answer (score 7):

There's air in the lines from the sounds of it, likely from them not correctly bleeding the system. An air bubble in the system will compress before the rest of the fluid in the lines, thus not actuating the brake callipers.

If you don't have the tools to bleed your brakes at home, you should take it back to the workshop and get them to asap.

Comment: *"get them to ... asap"* Does this need editing?

Answer (score 4):

went back and they bled the brakes again after telling me they were good twice and now they work like they did before the master cylinder went bad.  Problem solved.